# Integral of $ \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x} $.

Tags: calculus, integration

Im looking for a way to calculate:

$$ \int{\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}}  dx $$

I substituted $ u = \sqrt{x+1} $ and then $ dx = 2 * \sqrt{x+1}  du $ so I have:

$$ \int{\frac{u}{x} * 2 \sqrt{x+1} du } $$

$ x = u^2-1 $ 
and

$$ 2 \int{\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} } du  = 2 \int{\frac{u^2}{(u-1)(u+1)} } du $$

I'm not sure if this is correct. Maybe I had some errors on the way here.

But if this is correct. How would I proceed then?

Comment: Option 1: partial fractions.  Option 2:  use $u=\tfrac 23(x+1)^{3/2}$, then $du=\sqrt{x+1}dx$ and $x$ is easy to solve for in terms of $u$.

Comment: Keyword is partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: $$\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} = 1+\frac{1}{u^2-1}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did was correct. To finish it off, notice that
$$\dfrac{u^2}{u^2-1} = \dfrac{(u^2-1)+1}{u^2-1} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{u^2-1}$$
The integral can then be computed using partial fractions:
$$\dfrac{1}{u^2-1} = \dfrac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{1}{u-1} - \dfrac{1}{u+1} \right)$$

Comment: okay, so the trick was to factour out $ u^2-1 $ from $ u^2 $. Any tip for me to see this the next time? I know partial fraction decomposition but not when my numerator is $ u^2 $ Any other approaches to get there? I need to "learn" something out of it. Having this kind of "tricks" is not so easy for me.

Comment: @DominiqueLüber:  the translation from ${u^2\over u^2-1}$ to $1+{1\over u^2-1}$ is important, and partial fractions is also highly important.  Both of these tricks are necessary to have on your list of "things to look for when doing algebra".

Comment: @abiessu I really get that and I know how important that is. I will look for some videos / extra material to improve my skills.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $$\frac{u^{2}}{u^{2}-1}=1+\frac{1}{u^{2}-1}=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)$$